# Getting pose data for OpenGL Coordinate System using Google Tango with Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, graphics, augmented-reality, google-project-tango

I am using Unity with Tango and I am having problems getting pose data.
Unity application with Tango Unity SDK is built for Android device, device gets pose data and it sends it to the computer where additional processing is done using OpenGL.
My question is, in which coordinate system is pose data returned since I can't define engine like with C API?
Unity handles geting pose data like this, and nothing additional could be sent:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        GetEmulatedPoseAtTime(poseData, timeStamp, framePair);
#else // ANDROID
        int returnValue = API.TangoService_getPoseAtTime(timeStamp, framePair, poseData);
        if (returnValue != Common.ErrorType.TANGO_SUCCESS)
        {
            Debug.Log(CLASS_NAME + ".GetPoseAtTime() Could not get pose at time : " + timeStamp);
        }
 #endif
```

Just to prove that my application with OpenGL works as it should, I've created Tango project using C API with the same idea (get pose data and send it):

```
    TangoCoordinateFramePair pair;
    pair.base = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE;
    pair.target = TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE;

    base = TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_OPENGL;
    target = TANGO_SUPPORT_ENGINE_OPENGL;

    error = TangoSupport_getPoseAtTime(poseTimestamp, pair.base, pair.target, base, target, ROTATION_0, &pose);
```

... and this works.

I thought that data is maybe in Tango Coordinate System and I tried to convert pose data with C# equivalent functions to QuatTangoToGl and Vec3GlToTango form [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/tango_gl/src/conversions.cc), but still, it is not correct.

So, in which coordinate system is pose data in Unity SDK and is it possible to somehow define which engine I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I could expose function TangoSupport_getPoseAtTime in TangoSupport and add enums EngineType and RotationType (values are matched with C API).

So, I added this in TangoSupport.cs under TangoSupportAPI:

```
[DllImport(TANGO_SUPPORT_UNITY_DLL)]
public static extern int TangoSupport_getPoseAtTime(
            double timestamp, TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType baseFrame, TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType targetFrame,
            Common.EngineType baseEngine, Common.EngineType targetEngine, Common.RotationType rotation, [In, Out] TangoPoseData pose);
```

and added proper function in TangoSupport class. 
Now I get poses that are set correctly in OpenGL project.

Without defining engine types, given poseData is for Tango Coordinate System.